# Azure resource manager tempate : Is there a way to get resourceId with a regular expression representing resource name?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I wonder if there is a way to get a resourceId with name that matches a regular expression in another subscription. The reason is that during deployment a random postfix is generated and appended to resource name, so resource name is not known beforehand. I know the [resourceId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid) function could give you the resource Id if the resource name is known.

Comment: When using `resourceId()`, is the resource being deployed as part of the same template, or has it already been deployed beforehand as a completely separate deployment?

Comment: The resources have been deployed through a separate deployment in a different resource group. @jarrad_obrien

Comment: How come the names of the existing resources can't be used as parameters in the new template?

Comment: Its because the resource name are generated during deployment, and not known beforehand. I think there are ways to get around the question I asked, its just not as clean. @jarrar_obrien

Comment: I mean that in the second template, how come you can't create a parameter such as `namesOfExistingResources` and populate it with the existing resources? e.g. `namesOfExistingResources: ['myResource2834', 'myResource7482']`

Comment: @Jarrad_obrien. I am trying to minimize these hard coded inputs in the deployment pipeline. Thank you for your suggestion, its a clean way to get around the question I asked. But listing with regular expression would still be a nice feature to have, especially for large scale deployment, could help avoid many human errors~

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the output of the previous template as input to the new template:

[Azure ARM templates - using the output of other deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058494/azure-arm-templates-using-the-output-of-other-deployments)

Here is how to achieve this in Azure DevOps:

[How do I use ARM 'outputs' values another release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948549/how-do-i-use-arm-outputs-values-another-release-task)